# JCIFS SmbException

Tags: smb, jcifs

I am trying to access a shared folder in my company network via JCIFS. But when i try to list the files under the shared folder, it throws an SmbException as below,

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: 0xC000009A
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:316)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:218)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:176)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:954)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getType(SmbFile.java:1282)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doEnum(SmbFile.java:1733)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.listFiles(SmbFile.java:1715)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.listFiles(SmbFile.java:1648)
```

0xC000009A says it is a NT_STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES but what do i have to do to fix this. The shared folder is only accessible by myself. I used the follwoing url format.

```
smb://domain;username:password@ip-address/<foldername>
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 9):

I faced same error developing file upload to windows shares using JCIFS.

It turned out, target windows machine had an error entry in system log:

```
Source:        srv
Event ID:      2017
Task Category: None
Level:     Error 
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:     SERVER01
Description:   The server was unable to allocate from the
system nonpaged pool because the server reached the configured limit
for nonpaged pool allocations.
```

This error is (possibly) caused by using an older (SMB1, e.g. Windows XP [prooflink](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/svr-error-2017-windows-xp-cannot-connect-to-shares/9f7ddcae-eff1-4166-9754-f77f1d7b7378)) version of the protocol when connecting to modern (Vista and above) versions of Windows.

[This article](http://alan.lamielle.net/2009/09/03/windows-7-nonpaged-pool-srv-error-2017) contains a workaround for the problem. It requires editing the target machine's registry values, so I can't call it a full solution.

Answer (score 3):

Updated link for the registry changes needed:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/30919e4f-6810-48d6-8769-2cff61f07544/event-id-2017-the-server-was-unable-to-allocate-from-the-system-nonpaged-pool-because-the-server?forum=w7itpronetworking