# Plain text passwords are disabled NetBios remote connection

Tags: java, remote-access, netbios

I'm trying connect remotely to windows machine and fetch files from this machine.
this is my code,

```
 path = path.replace(":","");
        path = path.replace("\\","/");
        String smbpath="smb://"+host+":445/"+path; //c/alon2.txt";

        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user+":"+password);
        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(smbpath,auth);

        SmbFileInputStream input = new SmbFileInputStream(smbFile);
        Files.copy(input, destPath.toPath());
        System.out.println("completed fetching file");
        return destPath;
```

and I got this exception, "Plain text passwords are disabled",
i tried to put jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.disablePlainTextPasswords","true");
and it doesnt work, and i dont want to disable the smb 3rd party in the server.
Any idea?

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Plain text passwords are disabled
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbComTreeConnectAndX.writeParameterWordsWireFormat(SmbComTreeConnectAndX.java:129)
>       at jcifs.smb.AndXServerMessageBlock.writeAndXWireFormat(AndXServerMessageBlock.java:94)
>       at jcifs.smb.AndXServerMessageBlock.writeAndXWireFormat(AndXServerMessageBlock.java:166)
>       at jcifs.smb.AndXServerMessageBlock.encode(AndXServerMessageBlock.java:65)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doSend(SmbTransport.java:439)
>       at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.sendrecv(Transport.java:67)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:655)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:316)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:218)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:176)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.logon(SmbSession.java:147)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.logon(SmbSession.java:140)
>       at com.hp.autopass.usagehub.service.util.osutils.NetBiosConnection.authenticate(NetBiosConnection.java:47)
>       at com.hp.autopass.usagehub.service.NetBiosConnectionTest.authenticateTest(NetBiosConnectionTest.java:34)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.disablePlainTextPasswords","false");`
to enable plain text passwords. In your code you set this flag as `true`.

Comment: I have a same problem and when I tried to add specified configuration it throws another exception
Exception in thread "main" jcifs. Sm. SmbException: 0xC000009A
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:316)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:218)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:176)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:957)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)

Comment: On to the next step then ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317300/jcifs-smbexception